# Symfony 3.4.6 и версия PHP

Tags: php, symfony

С какой версией PHP работает Symfony 3.4.6 ?

Comment: В документации разве не указано?

Comment: Почему-то не могу найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для версии 3.4.x требуется PHP не ниже 5.5.9 (из [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/requirements.html)).

P.S. К слову, это легко ищется по запросу "symfony 3.4.6 system requirements".